# Neo4j console.log file

Tags: neo4j, neography

I am experiencing something strange: my console.log is filled with messages like this:

```
DONE:0
Got Location:http://localhost:8474/db/data/index/node/<index-name>/<property-name>/<property-value>/<some int value>
DONE:1
DONE:2
DONE:0
Got Location:http://localhost:8474/db/data/index/node/<index-name>/<property-name>/<property-value>/<some int value>
DONE:1
DONE:2
Got Location:http://localhost:8474/db/data/index/node/<index-name>/<property-name>/<property-value>/<some int value>
DONE:3
Got Location:http://localhost:8474/db/data/index/node/<index-name>/<property-name>/<property-value>/<some int value>
DONE:4
Got Location:http://localhost:8474/db/data/index/node/<index-name>/<property-name>/<property-value>/<some int value>
DONE:5
Got Location:http://localhost:8474/db/data/index/node/<index-name>/<property-name>/<property-value>/<some int value>
```

It's quite annoying, as the file grew to 1G in two days. These look like debug messages, but I can't find the culprit.

I am using Neo4j 1.9, gremlin plugin 1.5, neography 1.0.9

Comment: Maybe search for that `DONE:` log statement in the code? Maybe neography source? Is it on the client or server?

Comment: This is what I tried, but I didn't find anything. I don't know if the message comes from the server's side or the client's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in the file 'community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/batch/BatchOperationResults.java' two "System.out.println" on lines 69 and 72.

```
public void addOperationResult( String from, Integer id, String body, String location )
{
    if(firstResult)
        firstResult = false;
    else
        results.append(',');

    results.append( OPENING_CURLY );

    if ( id != null )
    {
        results.append( "\"id\":" )
                .append( id.toString() )
                .append( COMMA );
    }

    System.out.println("DONE:" + id);
    if ( location != null )
    {
        System.out.println("Got Location:" + location);
        locations.put( id, location );
        results.append( "\"location\":" )
                .append( JsonHelper.createJsonFrom( location ) )
                .append( COMMA );
    }
```